# Sending multidimensional checkbox array via ajax in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I'm trying to post the multidimensional array values using checkbox to server side. But unfortunately cannot figure out the way to do it with checkbox.

What I trying to do is posting the ID, (NAME, VALUE) using ajax but yet only send one single array.

```
 <input type="hidden" id="addon_id" value="8"> //value is dynamic
 <input type="checkbox"  name='addon[]' value="1.99"  title="Item 1"> //value and title are dynamic
 <input type="checkbox"  name='addon[]' value="5.99"  title="Item 2"> 
 <input type="checkbox"  name='addon[]' value="3.99"  title="Item 3">
```

**jQuery**

```
var addon = [];

   $.each($("input[name='addon[]']"), function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            addon.push($(this).val());
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo site_url('cart/add_to_cart'); ?>',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        addon_id: addon_id,
        addon: addon
      },
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function(response) {

        //response

      }
    });
```

**currently sending format**

```
[addon] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1.99
            [1] => 5.00
            [2] => 3.89
        )
```

**Array format trying to send**

```
 Array
   (
       
    [8] =>  Array(
                     [0] =>  Array( 
                                    [name] => ITEM 1
                                    [price] => 1.99
                                  )

                     [1] =>  Array( 
                                    [name] => ITEM 2
                                    [price] => 5.99
                                  ) 
  
                     [2] =>  Array( 
                                    [name] => ITEM 3
                                    [price] => 3.99
                                  )     

                        
                    )
        

  )
```

JSON

```
"8":{
      "0":{ 
            "name":"ITEM 1",
           "price":"1.99"
          },
      "1":{ 
            "name":"ITEM 2",
            "price":"5.99"
          },
      "2":{ 
        "name":"ITEM 3",
        "price":"3.99"
          } 
        
    }
```

Comment: your output is not clear , you want a json?  so could you show the json you want with the keys name in json format

Comment: Have a look,by refresh the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the loop you have to include both values in an array:

```
  $.each($("input[name='addon[]']"), function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            addon.push({"name":$(this).attr("title"), "price":$(this).val()});
        }
    });
```